# Angular routing not working. Throwing error component is not part of a module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am creating Angular 4 application and trying to implement basic routing. My application compiles fine but my routing isn't working

I am getting the error Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

I am yet to configure routerlinks but presume the routing should work from the requests in the browser.

When i click the home, the contents of home.component.html should load similarly 
clicking on edit, new , movie should do the same respectively

COuld somebody tell if i am going anywhere wrong in my imports. Specifically

with movie,home,edit & new

Here is the structure of my folders

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
    import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
    import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
    import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
    import {AppRoutingModule} from './approuting.module';
    import {HomeModule} from './home/home.module';
    import {MovieModule} from './movie/movie.module';
    import { MRDBCommonService } from './shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
    import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
    import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FooterbarComponent,
        TopbarComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        NotFoundComponent  
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        SharedModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants,
                  MRDBCommonService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**approuting.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie/movie.component';
import {HomeComponent}  from '../app/home/home.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {NewmovieComponent} from './movie/new/newmovie.component';
import {EditmovieComponent} from './movie/edit/editmovie.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{path : '', component : HomeComponent},
{path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent},
{path : 'new' , component : NewmovieComponent },
{path : 'edit' , component : EditmovieComponent },
{path: '**',component : NotFoundComponent}

];

@NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
     exports: [RouterModule]

})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**Home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the **`HomeModule`** inside the imports in your app.module.ts

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        SharedModule,
        HomeModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Create first SharedHomeComponent.ts

```
import { HomeComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NgModule,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,RouterModule
        ],
        exports: [HomeComponent],
        declarations: [HomeComponent]
    })
    export class SharedHomeComponent implements OnInit {
        ngOnInit(): void {
            //throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
        }
      constructor() {
       }
    }
```

Then after, Whenever you want to use HomeComponent then import into component related module **e.g.** *app.module.ts* or different module.
Then you can use the home component selector into multiple module components.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the "AlabalaModule" into the imports

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AlabalaModule
  ],
```

also you need spaces like tis -> { Alabala } ,
im pretty sure that {Alabala} is not valid syntax